# R Shiny: Download preset .csv file

Tags: r, shiny, download

I am working on a shiny app that allows the user to download an existing `.csv` file (called `template.csv`) that is located on the server (in a folder called "data").

Using `downloadHandler`, I do not get any output.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  downloadButton("download", label = "Download")
)

server <- function(input,output) {
  output$download <- downloadHandler(
  filename <- function() {
    "template_output.csv"
  }
  content <- function(file) {
    file.copy("./data/template.csv", file)
  }
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Where did I go wrong? Can someone help me make it work?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    downloadButton("download", label = "Download")
)

server <- function(input,output) {
    output$download <- downloadHandler(
        filename <- function() {
            "template_output.csv"
        },
        content <- function(file) {
            file.copy("./data/template.csv", file)
        }
    )
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```